# UIAlertView Not Showing iOS8

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, uialertview, ios8, internet-connection

Hey so i'm running the iOS8 beta on my phone and I'm having issues since I last updated my phone that my UIAlertViews are not appearing when they should be. I definitely have no changed the code in these sections and they were working fine before. 
Here's the relevant code. In short it loads a webview and when there's no internet connection it should display the alert saying there is no connection.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

  [[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.96f blue:0.33f     alpha:1.0]];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.sheffski.co.uk/forum/"]]];
[webView addSubview:activityInd];
timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(loading) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
-(void)loading{
if(!webView.loading)
    [activityInd stopAnimating];
else
    [activityInd startAnimating];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
//No Internet Connection error code
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)WebView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:@"You have no internet connection! Reload the app with a connection or try another page." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close App" otherButtonTitles:@"Continue", nil];
[alert show];

}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if(buttonIndex == 0){
    exit(0);
}

}
```

Unfortunately I cannot test it on iOS7.1 as i've found that Xcode5 occasionally feels like not playing fair with my code and is now saying I have errors to do with the MediaPlayer framework so I can only run in the Xcode6 beta (downloading the 7.1 simulators now). I was wondering if anyone can see anything inherently wrong with the code and if other people are having this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Use UIAlertController. UIAlertView has been deprecated in iOS 8.